# Finding the odds of games in the past

Tags: american-football

I'm interested in finding the odds (aka spread or latest line) of NFL games that were played in the past, as far back as the 1960's.  In general, the odds that were printed in newspapers.

Where can I find this information?

<sub>I am specifically **not** looking for gambling websites.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand your requirement about gambling websites. Wouldn't those be the most likely sources of such information?

Comment: @MichaelMyers Maybe I'll strike that.  Questions about gambling and fantasy football can easily wander into off-topic territory, and I'm trying to stay on-topic.  That said, almost all gambling websites that I've found hide or delete their line information as soon as the game ends.  But there were odds on games long before the internet was really used, before these gambling websites existed, and that information is just really hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for odds that were printed in newspapers, you already know where to look... newspapers.  Take a trip down to your local library, where they probably have 50-100 years of newspaper archives on microfilm.

Comment: Are any newspaper microfilms on the internet?  I thought Google was trying to do something like that but none of the publishers were cooperating.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_online_newspaper_archives